# Any plastic for long term storage of Puriss. Ethanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, materials, equipment

I'm being offered to share some puriss Ethanol. Can I store it long term in any plastic container without the slightest contamination/reaction from the plastic? I have HDPE, PET, but I could buy another type if it's affordable (please don't answer PTFE).

If not, would an HCl > distilled water pre-rinse be sufficient to store it in a glass bottle?

Comment: Regarding trace ontamination, then generally, organic liquids are best stored in glass ( avoiding extraction ) and inorganic liquids in plastics ( avoiding trace metals from glass ). Surely there are exceptions as hydrofluoric acid or oxidating liquids.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say for certain so take my advice with a grain of salt, but if you cannot use PTFE, than HDPE is almost as good. Very few chemicals I have ever used have ever interacted with it and if you need something unreactive, HDPE is a pretty safe bet on top of being abundantly available.

PET, although very transparent, is very hit and miss when it comes to reactivity and I wouldn't recommend it.